Is it possible to retreat during attacking?
In RimWorld, I just clicked to 'attack' another colony, then tried to find a'retreat' or 'flee' button, but failed.
Does that suggest that it is not possible to retreat' or 'flee' during an
attack that has already started?
I can imagine that it might be possible with save/load and save-modification, but are there other methods that are designed and can be used inside?
I have just tried to search in the wiki but didn't find related things mentioned.

To retreat just select all pawns and go to the border of the map. It will have a greenish/yellowish shade.
Bear in mind that if you had animals in your caravan you will lose them.
